# Failed to find the list schema for FeatureId list template ID 10000. Cannot create list in web "at URL "Lists/ListTest"

Tags: 2013, list

I am trying to create a SharePoint list declaratively but I have the error above.

According to this [site](http://innersharepoint.blogspot.be/2013/08/fixing-error-getuserlistschema-failed.html)
I should put the feature id on the list instance xml definition, but after doing it, the error persists.

My idea is just to create a custom list with a content type.

The code I used its the one generated automatically by VS 2012

List Instance elements

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <!-- Do not change the value of the Name attribute below. If it does not match the folder name of the List project item, an error will occur when the project is run. -->
    <ListTemplate
        Name="List1"
        Type="10000"
        BaseType="0"
        OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
        SecurityBits="11"
        Sequence="410"
        DisplayName="List1"
        Description="My List Definition"
        Image="/_layouts/15/images/itgen.png"/>
</Elements>
```

Schema xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="List1" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/List1" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" EnableContentTypes="TRUE">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>


    <ContentTypeRef ID="0x01">
        <Folder TargetName="Item" />
      </ContentTypeRef><ContentTypeRef ID="0x0120" /><ContentType ID="0x0100D17B974BA3B04BA6B1A80917DFB7F32A" Name="CT01" Group="Custom Content Types" Description="My Content Type" Inherits="TRUE" Version="0"><FieldRefs><FieldRef ID="{88903efe-ef05-4e72-b8be-1e89fb1920e3}" DisplayName="Status" Required="FALSE" Name="yyy_Status" /><FieldRef ID="{46E2BB3D-79C9-47BF-B267-275A53686DBB}" DisplayName="Start date" Required="TRUE" Name="yyy_StartDate" /><FieldRef ID="{8C90E0D3-80E3-4089-AD2C-F205B736BF50}" DisplayName="First name" Required="TRUE" Name="yyy_FirstName" /></FieldRefs></ContentType></ContentTypes>
    <Fields>

    <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title" DisplayName="$Resources:core,Title;" Required="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" MaxLength="255" /><Field ID="{88903efe-ef05-4e72-b8be-1e89fb1920e3}" StaticName="yyy_Status" Name="yyy_Status" DisplayName="Status" Type="Choice" Required="FALSE" Group="Test Site Columns"><CHOICES><CHOICE>Active</CHOICE><CHOICE>Completed</CHOICE><CHOICE>Archived</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field><Field ID="{46E2BB3D-79C9-47BF-B267-275A53686DBB}" StaticName="yyy_StartDate" Name="yyy_StartDate" DisplayName="Start date" Type="DateTime" Required="TRUE" Group="Test Site Columns"></Field><Field ID="{8C90E0D3-80E3-4089-AD2C-F205B736BF50}" StaticName="yyy_FistName" Name="yyy_FirstName" DisplayName="First name" Type="Text" Required="TRUE" Group="Test Site Columns"></Field></Fields>
    <Views>


    <View BaseViewID="0" Type="HTML" MobileView="TRUE" TabularView="FALSE">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>

        <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu"></FieldRef></ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>

          <FieldRef Name="Modified" Ascending="FALSE"></FieldRef></OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="AddNewAnnouncement" Location="Resource(wss,addnewitem)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_ONET_HOME)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View><View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=23" Url="AllItems.aspx">
        <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
        <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
        <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
        <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
        <ViewFields>

        <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"></FieldRef><FieldRef Name="yyy_Status" /><FieldRef Name="yyy_StartDate" /><FieldRef Name="yyy_FirstName" /></ViewFields>
        <Query>
          <OrderBy>

          <FieldRef Name="ID"></FieldRef></OrderBy>
        </Query>
        <ParameterBindings>
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
          <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
        </ParameterBindings>
      </View></Views>
    <Forms>
      <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
      <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

List Instance xml

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ListInstance Title="List1" OnQuickLaunch="TRUE" TemplateType="10000" Url="Lists/List1" Description="My List Instance" FeatureId="b36d6a54-4171-4a0b-8902-18b73505ac02"></ListInstance>
</Elements>
```

and the feature

```
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" Title="yyy - Test - List" ActivateOnDefault="FALSE" Id="b36d6a54-4171-4a0b-8902-18b73505ac02" Scope="Web" Version="1.0.0.0">
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="List1Instance\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="List1\Elements.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="List1\Schema.xml" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It went away after I added a FeatureID property to the ListInstance element and set it to the ID of the sitefeature that contained the listtemplate.

Comment: Dunno why this is downvoted. It's a valid possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
| Feature ID                           | Name                           | List Template |
|--------------------------------------|--------------------------------|---------------|
| 00bfea71-e717-4e80-aa17-d0c71b360101 | Document Library               | 101           |
| 00bfea71-1e1d-4562-b56a-f05371bb0115 | Form Library                   | 115           |
| 00bfea71-c796-4402-9f2f-0eb9a6e71b18 | Wiki Page Library              | 119           |
| 00bfea71-52d4-45b3-b544-b1c71b620109 | Picture Library                | 109           |
| 2510d73f-7109-4ccc-8a1c-314894deeb3a | Report Library                 | 433           |
| 29d85c25-170c-4df9-a641-12db0b9d4130 | Translation Management Library | 1300          |
| 00bfea71-dbd7-4f72-b8cb-da7ac0440130 | Data Connection Library        | 130           |
| 0be49fe9-9bc9-409d-abf9-702753bd878d | Slide Library                  | 2100          |
| 00bfea71-d1ce-42de-9c63-a44004ce0104 | Announcements                  | 104           |
| 00bfea71-7e6d-4186-9ba8-c047ac750105 | Contacts                       | 105           |
| 00bfea71-6a49-43fa-b535-d15c05500108 | Discussion Board               | 108           |
| 00bfea71-2062-426c-90bf-714c59600103 | Links                          | 103           |
| 00bfea71-ec85-4903-972d-ebe475780106 | Calendar                       | 106           |
| 00bfea71-a83e-497e-9ba0-7a5c597d0107 | Tasks                          | 107           |
| 00bfea71-513d-4ca0-96c2-6a47775c0119 | Project Tasks                  | 150           |
| 00bfea71-5932-4f9c-ad71-1557e5751100 | Issue Tracking                 | 1100          |
| 00bfea71-eb8a-40b1-80c7-506be7590102 | Survey                         | 102           |
| 00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100 | Custom List                    | 100           |
| 00bfea71-3a1d-41d3-a0ee-651d11570120 | Custom List in Datasheet View  | 120           |
| 29d85c25-170c-4df9-a641-12db0b9d4130 | Languages and Translators      | 1301          |
| 065c78be-5231-477e-a972-14177cc5b3c7 | KPI List                       | 432           |
```

Source: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/vinitt/2009/11/04/list-of-feature-id-listtemplate/